# Lock a server within a rack of several servers

Tags: rack, physical-security

I have a 42 RU Dell rack with several 2RU servers in it.  I need to prevent physical access to one of the servers in the rack, but not the others.  The face plate that comes with the Dell servers is no good as they are keyed generically (sp?) and pretty flimsy.

Is there some kind of locking panel I can install to prevent access to the front of the server without the key?  I've googled and only been able to find some for music equipment.

Comment: What physical access do you need to prevent? What are you trying to keep from happening? Is locking the front panel sufficient? Or do you need to protect the rear as well? What about the other ends of any cables (network especially?).

Answer (score 2):

Companies like MiddleAtlantic offer security covers that go over the front panels.

Comment: For instance, their hinged plexi security cover: http://www.middleatlantic.com/rackac/security/security.htm#2

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to take the dimensions of the lock (typically, this is done by overall back length of the lock and the length/shape of the locking tab) and replace it. I have done this for servers and cabinets where users have lost the keys. Many hardware parts catalogues (eg: CPC Farnell in the UK) sell lock assemblies. You may also be able to exchange the lock with one from another piece of kit.

The other thing I have seen done is to loop a laptop security cable through the handles at either end of the server and lock it so that the cable is across the front of the frontplate. This is not 100% secure and depends on the length of the locking cable, but where I have seen it done it would make it extremely difficult to get the cover off without damaging or scraping it.

On one site, we were considering whether we could widen the keyring hole in the server's key so that the laptop cable could be threaded through it, thus preventing the key from being turned, but we never pursued this idea.

Answer (score 0):

With a Dremel and a drill, you could install a [Lock Hasp (Examples)](http://www.lowes.com/pl_Lock+Hasps+Barrel+Bolts_4294807802_4294937087_?Ns=p_product_prd_lis_ord_nbr|0||p_product_quantity_sold|1).  Not using the arm, but rather the 90-degree protruding part, install it behind the door-jamb, cut out a slot in the door, and place a key lock or padlock through the hole.